# Twig block passed to embedded template

Tags: templates, embed, twig, block, extend

I'm using twig templates in a slim framework app. I have a template `page.phtml` which paginates an array of data and has several sub blocks intended for overriding per element specifics like paginating users, events, orders, etc.

**page.phtml**

```
<div class="page">
    {% block block1 %}default content{% endblock %}
    <ul>
    ...
    </ul>
    {% block block2 %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

I have an `event.phtml` template which embeds `page.phtml` and adds some other content to the page; it also overrides the default page's block1 content

**event.phtml**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Event Page</h1>
        {% embed "page.phtml" %}
            {% block block1 %}event page content{% endblock %}
        {% endembed %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a custom event page which needs only modify a few of the event page's blocks so I extended `event.phtml` like so

**custom_event.phtml**

```
{% extends "event.phtml" %}
{% block block2 %}overridden value{% endblock %}
```

and expected block2's overridden content to show up in the page.phtml template embedded by the parent template. I can output the value of block2 in the parent template and it's there, but in the embedded template it's not. I tried explicitly passing the block in `event.phtml` in the embed like so

```
{%embed "page.phtml" %}
    {% block block2 %}{{parent()}}{% endblock %}
    ...
{% endembed %}
```

But that yielded no difference. How do I get the overridden block2 from the `custom_event.phtml` template all the way through the extended `event.phtml` template and into the embedded `page.phtml` template?

Comment: Would a Twig extension be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Would this work? `{% block block2 %}{{ block("block2") }}{% endblock %}`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't, unless you're willing to output the block previous to using it in the embed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.

`{% embed %}` technically defines a new (anonymous) template which extends the embedded template (this is how it can overwrite blocks) and gets included into the current templating. This is really just syntactic sugar for `{% include %}` and `{% extends %}` to avoid having to store this partial template in its own file and include it only once.
Twig inclusion are not extendable by child templates. Only blocks of the current template are available for extension. And `event.phtml` does not have any blocks.

Answer (score 0):

They're not pretty, but I know of a couple of ways to achieve this.

#### Render the blocks in the parent template to variables

```
{% set the_block_content %}
    {% block the_block '' %}
{% endset %}

{% embed 'component.html.twig' %}
    {% block the_block the_block_content %}
{% endembed %}
```

#### Don't render the blocks in the parent template, then call them directly from within the embedded template

```
{% if false %}
    {% block the_block '' %}
{% endif %}

{% embed 'component.html.twig' %}
    {% block the_block block('the_block', _self) %}
{% endembed %}
```

Intersting to note how the value of `_self` appears to be decided at compile time from the template it's written in, rather than the runtime context.